# Text Gets Pulled Out Of Anchor Tag After Clicking "Add to Cart" Button.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, anchor

When first loading [this page](http://givemoreco.com/product/smile-move-book/) the "View Cart" button in the gray box is displayed correctly. After clicking the "Add To Cart" button the "View Cart" text is pulled out of the anchor tag (button) and repositioned below, leaving the button empty (but still clickable).

I kind of think it is the jQuery ajax add to cart action that is somehow removing the css from the anchor tags "viewCartBtn" class file, but I am not sure.

Can someone please help me figure out why this would be happening?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor tag text was actually being pulled out after the ajax request. After pouring over the ajax request and steps taken there after, I found that their was an extra closing slash on the anchor tag that was causing the text to pop out.

When clicking "add to cart" a ajax request processes the quantity field and then reloads just that panel. Somehow on the reload the extra slash was picked up different and caused the text to escape the tag. Crazy.

Thanks for taking a look and trying to help out Greg.

Answer (score 0):

After the ajax the text is really out of the anchor

```
<a class="viewCartBtn" href="/cart"></a>
VIEW CART
```

So maybe there'S an error in your markup when you are adding you

```
 <p> 1 item(s) added to your cart </p>
```

Paste us your html and jquery if you want more help , or do a fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the response Greg. I just figured out what was going on... please see my answer below. Thanks!